# Implementing external WSDL-obtained interface

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

(Urgh, this will hopefully make sense. I'm likely not knowledgeable enough to make intelligent searches...)

So, the idea here is that I am provided a WSDL file that I, successfully, imported to Visual Studio as a Service Reference. I can see the interface it generated just fine.

I have created a Web Service on my own project. There, in IMyService, I exposed the methods I needed, and in MyService.cs, I implement both IMyService and IWSDLInterface.

The logic goes as follows:

```or-tag
[ServiceContract(Namespace = Constants.Namespace)]
public interface IMyService
{
/// <summary>
/// A simple WebGet that runs a test.
/// </summary>
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Test")]
[OperationContract]
void Test();

[OperationContract]
CustomObject1 IWSDLInterfaceMethod1(CustomObjectReturn1 firstOperation);

[OperationContract]
CustomObject2 IWSDLInterfaceMethod2(CustomObjectReturn2 secondOperation);

}
```

This is my exposed Service. Here is the external interface that I obtained:

```or-tag
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://eventmanager.xmlns.oracle.com/", 
ConfigurationName="ImportedWSDL.InterfaceIWantToImplement")]
public interface InterfaceIWantToImplement{

    // Example for IWSDLInterfaceMethod1; there are more things to implement here.

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="IWSDLInterfaceMethod1", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    ImportedWSDL.customObject1 IWSDLInterfaceMethod1(ImportedWSDL.customObjectReturn1 firstOperation);


}
```

Implementing that interface in MyService.cs worked fine. The problem is that, when calling MyService via SOAP, I always hit the following exception:

```or-tag
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter 
[customObjectReturn1.firstParameter]. //changed name to make sense with the above code 
The InnerException message was 'The constructor with parameters 
(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext) is not found in ISerializable 
type 'System.Delegate'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

If I understand this correctly, this message states that SOAP calls to my service are failing for an inability to deserialize the first parameter of the customObjectReturn1. However, this doesn't make a lot of sense to me - I can browse my WSDL and I see all of the objects described; importing the WSDL to SoapUI *does* recognize the expected parameters and their properties, so they're obviously there.

[Constructor not found during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673444/constructor-not-found-during-deserialization)   This had some information about a fix, but since I do not control the classes directly (They're on the autogenerated code for ImportedWSDL), it wouldn't make a lot of sense to me to edit autogenerated code.

So,

- Is this a legitimate way to implement an external WSDL's interface?
- If so, am I able to add serialization tags to MyService.cs in a way that wouldn't force me to edit autogenerated code?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: System.Delegate is an abstract class, although it has the SerializationAttribute, there is no implementation. You can't serialize/deserialize System.Delegate. The derived class must implement the special constructor that deserialization calls. In your case, it appears, it does not. This would be on the developers of the web service you are trying to consume to fix.

Comment: Yup. Turns out the problem really was on the imported WSDL getting me unserializable objects. If you answer this as not a full comment, I'll accept it.

I was forced to comment the auto generated comment regarding that property. That got it to work. public partial class objectImportedFromWSDL : object , >>>>>>System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged<<<<<<<  That was neither on the documentation i was provided with, nor did it work without this bit commented.

Comment: Posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment above:

System.Delegate is an abstract class, although it has the SerializationAttribute, there is no implementation. You can't serialize/deserialize System.Delegate. The derived class must implement the special constructor that deserialization calls. In your case, it appears, it does not. This would be on the developers of the web service you are trying to consume to fix.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. My service provider will have to make some changes to allow this serialization. For testing purposes, I now commented the auto generated code's faulty lines.