# C# Deserialization exception on the object inherited from Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

Why am I getting deserialization exception **"The constructor to deserialize an object of type 'SerializeTest.TryMe' was not found"** in the first implementation of class but not in the second?

1st implementation:

```
[Serializable]
public class TryMe : IDictionary<int, string>
{
    Dictionary<int, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    public TryMe() {}

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }
    // all other IDictionary members are implemented below...
    ......
}
```

2nd implementation:

```
[Serializable]
public class TryMe : Dictionary<int, string>
{
    public int Dummy { get; set; } = 5;
    public TryMe() {}
}
```

Serialization/deserialization code:

```
var tryMe = new TryMe();
tryMe[5] = "a"; tryMe[9] = "b"; tryMe[4] = "c";
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\11.obj", FileMode.Create))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fs, tryMe);
}

tryMe = null;
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\11.obj", FileMode.Open))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    tryMe = (TryMe)formatter.Deserialize(fs); // Exception here with 2nd implementation of TryMe!!
}
```

Also other then serialization issue when should I prefer to inherit `IDictionary` and when `Dictionary`?
Is there a canonical way/rule for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor not found during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673444/constructor-not-found-during-deserialization)

Comment: @LouisGo: to elaborate: my question is why do I have to add ctor `public TryMe(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }` in one case but not in other?

Comment: `IDictionary` implementation is handled by class itself, while `Dictionary` serialization implementation is NOT done by `TryMe`. How would serializer know where to put dickionary keypair data, if `TryMe` does not specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question:**

> Why am I getting deserialization exception **"The constructor to
>   deserialize an object of type 'SerializeTest.TryMe' was not found"** in
>   the first implementation of class but not in the second?

**Answer:**

Documentation of interface [`ISerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=netframework-4.8) says:

> The `ISerializable` interface implies a constructor with the signature
>   `constructor (SerializationInfo information, StreamingContext context)`.
>   At deserialization time, the current constructor is called only after
>   the data in the `SerializationInfo` has been deserialized by the
>   formatter.

(Let's call `constructor (SerializationInfo information, StreamingContext context)` a deserialization constructor.)

So from documentation we know that for classes that implement `ISerializable` a deserialization constructor is mandatory.

Class [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) implements `ISerializable` and your class `TryMe` (from the second sample) inherits `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. During deserialization deserializer considers `TryMe` as a class that implements `ISerializable` and looks for deserialization constructor. Deserializer cannot find it and throws exception.

Interface [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) does not implement `ISerializable` therefore deserialization constructor is not needed. In this case `TryMe` can be deserialized without deserialization constructor. Exception is not thrown.

---

**Question:**

> Also other then serialization issue when should I prefer to inherit
>   IDictionary and when Dictionary?
>
> Is there a canonical way/rule for this?

**Answer:**

For serialization it is possible to inherit either `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. But if you inherit `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` a deserialization constructor must be added to your class.

*When should you prefer to inherit `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and when `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?* It depends on the problem you solve. In general we can consider two cases:

1. If you need to implement a class with custom `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` functionality and functionality of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not satisfy your requirements than you should prefer to inherit `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.
2. If functionality of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` satisfy your requirements and, optionally, you need to change or add to it you own functionality than you should prefer to inherit `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

If you implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` by delegating appropriate methods to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` like in you first sample that it likely that you don't need to implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. In this case you should inherit `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

```
// Sample, when it is better to inherit Dictionary<TKey, TValue> 
// instead of implementing IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.
[Serializable]
public class TryMe : IDictionary<int, string>
{
    Dictionary<int, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public string this[key]
    {
        get { return _dictionary[key]; }
    }

    // Other IDictionary<TKey, TValue> members are implemented the same way.
}
```